# Most efficient way to populate vector with indices corresponding to columns of a matrix in constructor?

Tags: c++, arrays, performance, vector, std

I have a dynamic `Matrix` template class that I wish to create a vector and populate it with indices that go down the columns instead of the rows. As you've probably guessed from what I just said, I'm storing the actual data of the matrix in row-major form in a `std::vector<T>`. Here is a simplified version of my Matrix class definition with the relevant parts only.

```
template<typename T>
class Matrix {
    public:
        Matrix(std::size_t m, std::size_t n, const T &elem = T());
        Matrix(const std::vector<T> &vec, std::size_t m, std::size_t n); 
        Matrix(std::initializer_list<T> list, std::size_t m, std::size_t n);

    private:
        typedef std::vector<std::size_t> reindex_scheme;

        std::vector<T> _data;
        reindex_scheme _colindices;
        std::size_t _m;
        std::size_t _n;

};
```

Basically, what I want to happen, is when given this piece of code:

```
std::vector<int> input {1, 2, 4, 6, 5, 4};
Matrix<int> A(input, 2, 3); // creates a 2x3 matrix with entries 1 2 4
                            //                                   6 5 4
```

for it to store the following in `_colindices` in this order:

```
0 3 1 4 2 5
```

(if you catch what I'm doing, I'm just grabbing the index of the element if you traverse the matrix like this:

```
 |   /|   /|
 | /  | /  |
\/   \/   \/
```

hopefully you can figure out the arrows)

What I have so far for the constructors is the "naive" `for`-based method:

```
template<typename T>
Matrix<T>::Matrix(std::size_t m, std::size_t n, const T &elem)
    : _data(m * n, elem),
      _colindices(m * n), 
      _m(m),
      _n(n) {
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < _n; i++)
        for (std::size_t j = 0; j < _m; j++)
            _colindices[i * _m + j] = j * _n + i;
}

template<typename T>
Matrix<T>::Matrix(const std::vector<T> &vec, std::size_t m, std::size_t n)
    : _data(vec),
      _colindices(m * n), 
      _m(m),
      _n(n) {
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < _n; i++)
        for (std::size_t j = 0; j < _m; j++)
            _colindices[i * _m + j] = j * _n + i;
}

template<typename T>
Matrix<T>::Matrix(std::initializer_list<T> list, std::size_t m, std::size_t n)
    : _data(list),
      _colindices(m * n), 
      _m(m),
      _n(n) {
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < _n; i++)
        for (std::size_t j = 0; j < _m; j++)
            _colindices[i * _m + j] = j * _n + i;
}
```

**Also, as a side note you can see the stupid code duplication that I'm doing for the three constructors. If you know of the best way to integrate three into one or at least three into two, please tell me here too.** (sorry, this became sort of a double-question)

This `for` method works, but obviously it's O(mn), and I like to think that there is a better, more efficient way, maybe with some `std` methods? I was thinking of something like making a vector with `0 3` and then iterating over it, composing a new vector by incrementing each element maybe by `std::transform` or something, and adding that to the end of the final vector until I get to the end (if you get what I'm saying). Sort of like

```
Loop Iteration 1:
0 3
Loop Iteration 2:
0 3 1 4
Loop Iteration 3:
0 3 1 4 2 5
```

What are your thoughts?

Comment: Why do you need to store those indices? Why not just calculate the index required at some accessor?

Comment: Unless your goal is to inspect the contents with a debugger, there's nothing useful that can be done with the class you've shown. How do you plan on accessing the elements? That's the key to deciding how to manage data. It's fairly straightforward to write an iterator that accesses stored data in row-major order and an other iterator that accesses stored data in column-major order, if you're planning on using iterators (which you probably should be doing...).

Comment: @PeteBecker I am, I've omitted like 95% of the actual code. Planning on using `boost::permutation_iterator` to achieve column-major iteration, and since the data's stored in row-major anyways, the `Matrix<T>::row_iterator` is literally just a typedef of the `_data` iterator.

Comment: `permutation_iterator` sounds like overkill for such a straightforward mapping. There are only two numbers involved: n and m, and they're already known. An nxm matrix (regardless of how it's implemented) to remap rows to columns has a **lot** of redundancy.

Comment: @PeteBecker I have overloaded `operator[]` to give a proxy object to simulate `operator[][]`, I just thought that idea of using an already existing iterator writing interface was easier than going through the gritty details myself.

Comment: Despite rumors to the contrary, iterators aren't hard to write. They're just tedious. I go through a progression: requirements for input iterator, requirements for output iterator, requirements for forward iterator, requirements for bidirectional iterator, requirements for random-access iterator. Each one adds a handful of things.

Answer (score 1):

My first thoughts are that your program is done since long and my answer is too late.

But then, maybe other SO users also want to hear about possible solutions.

Reading that you are using a

> row-major form in a std::vector

suggests the idea to use a `std::valarray`. With `std::slice` (or other type of slices) you can simply operate on all kind of indices that you can imagine. The index operator `[]` together with slices will calculate the indeces only when you need them. That is very powerful and fast.

The standard C++ approach for building a matrix is to use a `std::vector` of `std::vector` of Type. And then accessing that data or do operations with it. Please note: A `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` uses also contiguous memory. You can just access it differently. For example: Rows are very easy to access. You can just use the first dimenion. For a `std::vector<std::vector<int>> data;`, you can simply write `data[row]` to access all columns in that row.

With columns this is more difficult. My guess is that you want to a achieve somehow to access the columns. Otherwise there would be no need to calculate the indices for columns or in column order.

The disadvantage of this is that you cannot use your matrix with the `algorithm` library. Without having the iterators available, hm, difficult.

I can present you a solution for a matrix that has iterators for rows and columns. For that we use a vector of references to the correct values in the `std::vector<std::vector<int>> data;`, organized by columns. Then we can iterate over rows and columns and use the `std::algorithm`s.

For speed optimization the column reference could be created whenn needed. That would reduce the complexity in the constructor.

For your side node: Repeated code in the constructor. Please create a private function in your class and call it in the constructor.

Please see a skeleton of a Matrix with some test code (MSVS19):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <tuple>
#include <sstream>
#include <numeric>


// Unfortunately the std::reference_wrapper does not work as expected.
// So we will build our own one
class IntRef
{
    // Here we will store the reference
    std::tuple<int&> t;
public:
    // Constructor. Take reference and store it in tuple
    IntRef(int&& intV) : t(intV) {}

    // Assignment to the referenced value
    int operator =(const int i) { std::get<0>(t) = i; return i; }

    // Explicit type cast to int&
    operator int& () { return std::get<0>(t); }

    // And, return the reference
    decltype(&std::get<0>(t)) operator&() { return &std::get<0>(t); }
};


// Some definitions to make reading easier
using IntRefV = std::vector<IntRef>;
using MatrixCIterator = std::vector<IntRef>::iterator;
using Columns = std::vector<int>;
using MatrixRIterator = Columns::iterator;


// The matrix
class Matrix
{
public:
    // Constructor defines the matrix size
    Matrix(size_t numberOfRows, size_t numberOfColumns);

    // Iterators for rows are simple, becuase we have vectors of columns. Use unterlying iterator
    MatrixRIterator rowIterBegin(size_t row) { return data[row].begin(); }
    MatrixRIterator rowIterEnd(size_t row) { return data[row].end(); }

    // Column iterator is complicated. Retzurn iterator to vevtor of references to column values
    MatrixCIterator columnIterBegin(size_t column) { return columnReferences[column].begin(); }
    MatrixCIterator columnIterEnd(size_t column) { return columnReferences[column].end(); }

    // Access data of matrix
    std::vector<int>& operator [] (const size_t row) { return data[row]; }

    // And, for debug purposes. Output all data
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Matrix& m) {
        std::for_each(m.data.begin(), m.data.end(), [&os](const Columns & columns) {std::copy(columns.begin(), columns.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(os, " ")); std::cout << '\n'; });
        return os;
    }
protected:
    //The matrix, vector of vector of int
    std::vector<Columns> data;

    // The references to columns in data
    std::vector<IntRefV> columnReferences{};
};

// Constructor. Build basic matrix and then store references to columns in data 
Matrix::Matrix(size_t numberOfRows, size_t numberOfColumns) : data(numberOfRows, std::vector<int>(numberOfColumns)), columnReferences(numberOfColumns)
{
    for (size_t column = 0; column < numberOfColumns; ++column)
        for (size_t row = 0; row < numberOfRows; ++row)
            columnReferences[column].emplace_back(IntRef(std::move(data[row][column]))); // Std::move creates a rvalue reference (needed for constructor, nothing will be moved)
}



// Some test data for the istream_iterator
std::istringstream testData("1 2 10");



// Test the matrix
int main()
{
    // Define a matrix with 3 rows and 4 columns
    Matrix matrix(3, 4);
    // Test 1: Fill all values in column 2 with 42
    for (MatrixCIterator ci = matrix.columnIterBegin(2); ci != matrix.columnIterEnd(2); ++ci) {
        *ci = 42;
    }
    std::cout << matrix << "Column 2 filled with 42\n\n";

    // Test 2: Read input from istream and copy put that in column 1
    std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<int>(testData), 3, matrix.columnIterBegin(1));
    std::cout << matrix << "Column 1 filled with testData '" << testData.str() << "'\n\n";

    // Test 3: Copy column 2 to cout (Print column 2)
    std::copy(matrix.columnIterBegin(2), matrix.columnIterEnd(2), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << "This is column 2\n\n";

    // Test 4: Sum up the first 2 values of column 1 and show result
    std::cout << "\nSum of first 2 values of column 1:  " << std::accumulate(matrix.columnIterBegin(1), matrix.columnIterBegin(1) + 2, 0) << "\n\n";

    // Test 5: Fill all values in row 0 with 33
    std::for_each(matrix.rowIterBegin(0), matrix.rowIterEnd(0), [](int& i) { i = 33; });
    std::cout << matrix << "Row 0 filled with 33\n\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Hope this gives an idea on how it could work